# Is there feature of retrieve group member history (when created or deleted) in microsoft graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-groups

As the title says, I'm curious.

I know that graph api has a function to look up group members, but it seems impossible to track the addition or deletion of members between those requests.

Plus, the exact dateTime that was added or deleted as additional members.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the concept of using delta to tracking changes in groups.

Documentation

[delta query overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview?tabs=http)

[get incremental changes for groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups?tabs=http)

[group: delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)